# Emberjs: Conditional redirect in router

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

Is there a way to have a conditional redirect in the Ember.js Router, without breaking internal consistency of the router?

Comment: Can you explain a little more why you're transitioning to a different route from `connectOutlets`? (I'm kind of a noob in ember, so maybe I just don't understand what you're trying to do)

Comment: By the way, routes now have a `redirect:` element you can override, it is in the current guide.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you could do (as of today), is something like that:

```
root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
        enter: function(router) {
            var logged = /* get from appropriated source... */;
            Ember.run.next(function() {
                if (logged) {
                    router.transitionTo('loggedIn');
                } else {
                    router.transitionTo('loggedOut');
                }
            });
        }
    }),

    loggedIn: Ember.Route.extend({
        // ...
    }),

    loggedOut: Ember.Route.extend({
        // ...
    })
})
```

Do not miss the `Ember.run.next` as while you are in `enter`, the state transition is always pending, so you have to transition after that.

We use it as shown for authent, but you could imagine using it for whatever condition you have to...

Comment: If you do it on `connectOutlets` instead of `enter` you shouldn't need the `Ember.run.next`.

Comment: do you have an example how to do it with `connectOutlets`?

Comment: Well, the code is exactly the same, except the wrapping inside `Ember.run.next(function () { ... });`

Answer (score 3):

The new router now includes a

```
beforeModel
```

hook which you could over-ride to include conditional logic while transitioning to a route. 
The beforeModel hook will be called before the

```
model
```

hook is called and it gets passed a

```
transition
```

object. You can decide if you want to redirect to another route using

```
transitionToRoute()
```

or you could abort the transition if you don't want to redirect by calling

```
transition.abort()
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may be looking for conditional transitions.  This is covered in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617701/ember-js-routing-conditionally-prevent-route-state-change/11673376#11673376), the TLDR of which is to check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjdivad/KsHCN/).