# Google sign in with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, coffeescript, google-plus

I'm quite new to Ember.js, went through tutorial, read a bit of documentation and prepared really simple apps, mostly using Fixtures.
Tried a bit Ember-data, but since it's not yet production-ready, I will not be using it (neither Ember-auth).

I'm trying to implement Google Sign in within Ember application.

I would like to go through with [client-side signin](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#using_the_client-side_flow), and then after getting the token from Google, I will post it back to my backend, to either create an account or new token for communication with my backend.

The problem here is, I have to setup the Google+ button appropriately and give it e.g. a callback, that will be called when data from Google+ are ready to be provided [especially the token I need to authorize to my serv].

How it should be done with Ember.js?

The other thing is, how I should setup the Ember application, to redirect to 'login' if user is not yet authenticated?

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888657/how-should-i-pass-users-login-status-to-my-ember-js-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190928/emberjs-conditional-redirect-in-router/11192467#11192467) posts, but I don't know how to apply them to my case.

Answer (score 1):

Please see following example, it might give you some idea
http://jsbin.com/eQOZoGe/3/edit